# WebGL color quantization

Tags: webgl

I'm making a WebGL game in a 90s DOS games style. I'm trying to use a shader which would quantize colors to get reduced colors look. I found this solution: [Palette reduction to pre-defined palette](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/80577/palette-reduction-to-pre-defined-palette), however I only get 4 colors when I apply the shader (as in the picture). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You want the code of the other question giving an output of only 4 colours, is that it?

Comment: I get only 4 colors, but I would like to get 256. I edited the question.

Comment: Could you edit to clarify what code you're using, and what it's intended to do? Have you tried debugging the problem, and if so, how?

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have a specific 256 colors palette in mind, you could just use the "8-bit truecolor" as described at [8-bit color Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8-bit_color).

To do that, you need to map R and G channels onto 8 values (3 bits each), and B onto 4 values (2 bits).
Those 8 bits together make up 256 possible colors.

Provided your gl_FragColor is already determined, the lines below will map its color to one of 256 values:

```
vec3 color_resolution = vec3(8.0, 8.0, 4.0);
vec3 color_bands = floor(gl_FragColor.rgb * color_resolution) / (color_resolution - 1.0);
gl_FragColor = vec4(min(color_bands, 1.0), gl_FragColor.a);
```

The `min` clamping in the last line might not be necessary, this depends on the color buffer's format, you might keep it if unsure or take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26786711/will-the-fragment-shader-automatically-clamp-the-color-value-to-its-range.

Comment: Note that this code does not minimise the color difference with the original pixel. Another formula which does is: `floor(gl_FragColor.rgb * (color_resolution - 1.0) + 0.5) / (color_resolution - 1.0);`. In a perfect world you would also have to perform gamma correction before quantisation.